# C# box or copy when passing structs by reference?

Tags: c#, struct, boxing

Does c# box a struct here?

```
struct S { int x; }

void foo(ref S s) { s.x = 1; }

main { 
  var s = new S();
  foo(ref s); <-- boxing??
}
```

I have heard weird stuff about structs in classes.  Is there boxing here?  is this passing a copy of the member?

```
class C { S s; }

main { 
  var c = new C();
  foo(ref c.s); <-- boxing here?? copy here???
}
void foo(ref S s) { s.x = 1; }
```

Comment: What would be the point of `ref` if it resulted in a copy being made? That's what happens without `ref`. So `ref`, in order to not be totally redundant, has to be different by... not making a copy.

Comment: I am a c++ developer.  When I look at what c# does, everything seems redundant!  :)  I want to know precisely what something is going to cost me before I use it.  So why wouldn't ref on a value type box the value type so it could pass it like a reference type.  Just askin.

Comment: There is no copy or boxing in either of your code snippets.

Comment: @johnnycrash Boxing it is, by definition, making a copy of the value.  If you provide a copy to the method, it wouldn't be a reference to the *variable* passed in.  Passing a parameter by reference in C# has *identical* semantics to passing a parameter by reference in C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So `Struct` is value type if you read the documentation of ref

> Do not confuse the concept of passing by reference with the concept of
>   reference types. The two concepts are not the same. A method parameter
>   can be modified by ref regardless of whether it is a value type or a
>   reference type. **There is NO boxing of a value type when it is passed
>   by reference.**

[**ref (C# Reference)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

Here explanation what exactly ref is doing.

> The ref keyword causes an argument to be passed by reference, not by
>   value. The effect of passing by reference is that any change to the
>   parameter in the called method is reflected in the calling method.

Comment: What about the case when the struct is a member of a class?

Comment: @johnnycrash the Struct is still value type so no difference.

Comment: yes but the class is not pinned, it can be moved by the garbage collector - I'm really curious what's actually in the "ref" thing passed to the method.